# how can sendmail server add auto increment number on the same subject

Tags: sendmail

I have a sendmail server. I want to add an auto increment number on the subject when everyone reply the mail.

For example:

1. I send a mail and the subject is "aaaa", the server can switch the
   subject to "aaaa" [000]
2. when my partner reply the mail, the server
   can switch the subject to "aaaa" [001]

I am a chinese guy.
My Enghlish is so bad.
Apologize for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need `sendmail` to rewrite emails through a [milter](https://www.milter.org/milters/contentmods/alphabetical/1). Some serious assembly will be required, and you probably want to make sure that your milter-code doesn't accidentally break stuff, even in the weirdest circumstances for any other email. On the other hand, just matching the `Subject` against a regular expression and replacing it should not be too difficult.

I doubt there is ready-made software for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I also think there is a ready-made software in somewhere,but I can not found with google. Can you give me some key word in search with google?